# Logging query in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Would it be possible to extract only the query + possible comments from the context.Database.Log?

Example of what I want:
[image: Example of what I want]

Right now I am using the following code to extract this log:

`Context.Database.Log = Console.Write;`

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried understanding the documentation on logging and intercepting, searching stackoverflow and that is basically it. Don't really know what to search for.

Comment: Ef core or ...? What version are you using

Comment: I am using EF 6, not core

Comment: Problem is , ef generates the sql statement so getting comments is impossible afaik.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx

Comment: I just need the full query, the parameters right now are inside those comments. 
I don't need the comments per se, as long as I have the parameters.